# Why do I automatically get a period (.) in my MANPATH?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, manpage, fish

I'm setting `MANPATH` to `:bla`, yet when I try to use it, its value has suddenly turned into `.:bla` and this completely changes the meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have run into a bug in the Fish shell, version 2.6.0, which accidentally changed colon-separated elements of `MANPATH` (or other environment variables) into periods. This happens even when `MANPATH` was set in `bash` before you started `fish`.

Comment: Is that a bug? An empty element in such colon-separated directory lists is usually treated as meaning the current directory (and `:bla` has a leading, empty element), so this is just making it explicit.

Comment: Yes. An empty element in MANPATH doesn't mean the current directory, but rather the default configuration in /etc/manpath.config.